# How can I use icon in drop down menu using Bootstrap and Font Awesome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I want a drop down menu in which I can select country names, and in the drop down menu I also want flag icons of respective countries. For example, list India with India's flag.

```
<div class="ui-widget2">
    <span>
        <input id="inputbox" placeholder="Country Name" type="text" 
            class="countries" style="width:15%;">
    </span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code. This code is using bootstrap

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Country
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="india.jpg" />India</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```